# Unable to get data while running cordava android application

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am running cordova application on android platform. It shows me these two errors in chome inspect element.

1)Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

2)Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

This is the code for mainActivity :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        loadUrl("someUrl");
        LOG.e("launchUrl is",launchUrl);
    }
}
```

Please help me with this. I am unable to find the reason behind this

Answer (score 0):

You can't check if the extras are null or not in this way. The error comes from the '=' after the '!'.
Please have a closer look at this question: [Check if extras are set or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255618/check-if-extras-are-set-or-not)