# Is it possible to open intent that require extras without passing it?

Tags: android, android-intent

So i have intent that require some extras,but i was thinking is it possible to open it without passing extras and not getting null pointer?

EDIT: I have activity A and activity B. When i press button im passing few strings as extras to activity B. If its not passed,I will get null pointer and app will crash. What i want is, is it possible to check if there is extras passed,and if its passed to get them,if its not passed continue without it and not get null pointer error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell if Intent extras exist in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408419/how-do-i-tell-if-intent-extras-exist-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to check it. You need to use `Intent.hasExtra(String name)` where `name` is the name of the variable you want to check whether it was passed or not. For example: you place inside `Intent` string called `firstName` and then you want to use it in another activity. So here's the code you should place in the second activity:

```
if(Intent.hasExtra("firstName")) //Intent.hasExtra() return true or false
{
String firstName = Intent.getStringExtra("firstName");
//place here code you want to execute if intent contains firstName
}
else
{
//place here code you want to execute if intent does not contain firstName
}
```

Related question: [Check if extras are set or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255618/check-if-extras-are-set-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

in A.java:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
  intent.putExtra("data","my custom data here");
  startActivity(intent);
```

in B.java:

```
String data;
  if (getIntent().hasExtra("data") && getIntent().getStringExtra("data")!=null){ //add a check like that
     data=getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
  }else{
        //add your condition when data parameter is not there or null
  }
```